# Android Bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer SIGSEGV

Tags: android, android-bitmap, segmentation-fault

I have created a Camera Preview using OpenGL (GLSurfaceView), and as frames are getting rendered i'm using a cycle of PBO's to buffer frames to be processed.

When I start my shutdown processes for the camera and various components I get a SIG SEGV when converting the ByteBuffer to an Bitmap via Bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer.

Is there a way to check if the ByteBuffer is a valid image before converting it to a bitmap?

```
    // Map to buffer to a byte buffer, this is our pixel data
    ByteBuffer pixelsBuffer = (ByteBuffer) GLES30.glMapBufferRange(GLES30.GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0, mViewWidth * mViewHeight * 4, GLES30.GL_MAP_READ_BIT);

    // Copy the image data into the bitmap
    mBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(pixelsBuffer); // This line causes SIG SEGV
```